# Open two st terminals in a zsh script that in the same time start a program

Tags: zsh

So I would like to write a zsh script that opens up two new st terminals that execute the program and then close the window when done. I thought something like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 2); do st -c "java Program"&; done
```

but for some reason it does not work. Do anyone know why?

Comment: `zsh` has a better loop construct for this: `repeat 2; do ...; done`.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The shell code is fine; the only problem would seem to be in the exact `st` command used as the body of the loop.

Comment: I have given an answer that I found work very well, the one I stated did not and I guess it is because some form of segmentation fault. Figured I leave it up to help people in the future. Plus that it takes 2 days for me to accept a solution from myself

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you had self-answered. Consider using `repeat`, though, if just to simplify your loop.

Comment: I will try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
for i in $(seq 1 2); do st java program& done
```

works

or

```
repeat 2 do st java program & done
```

as presentend from @chepner, also from the comment section

Comment: In reference to my comment on the question, `repeat 2 do st java program & done` or `repeat 2 { st java program & }`.